# getting id from url in reactRouter v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am following an ecommerce tutorial, which was done with react V5 and I'm trying to remake it in react V6. Problem I faced includes url. I am building **Order details** page, which should contain details about the placed order. After clicking **"Place Order"** button I am getting an error, saying: **tched leaf route at location "/order/34" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.**

**OrderScreen.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Form, Button, Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Card, ListGroupItem } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { Redirect, Link, useNavigate, useParams, useLocation, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getOrderDetails } from '../actions/orderActions'
import { ORDER_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/orderConstants'

function OrderScreen({match}) {


    
    const orderId = match.params.id

    const orderDetails = useSelector(state => state.orderDetails)
    const { order, error, loading } = orderDetails

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    if(!loading && !error){
        order.itemsPrice = order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0).toFixed(2)
    }
    

    useEffect(() => {
    if(!order || order._id !== Number(orderId)){
            dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId))
            console.log("yes")
        }
    }, [dispatch,navigate,order,orderId])

    return loading ? (
        <Loader/>
    ) : error ? (
        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
    ) : (
            <div>
                <Row>
                <Col md={8}>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Shipping</h2>

                        <p>
                        <strong>Shipping: </strong>
                        {order.shippingAddress.address}, {order.shippingAddress.city},
                        {'  '}
                        {order.shippingAddress.postalCode},
                        {'  '}
                        {order.shippingAddress.country}.
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Payment Method</h2>

                        <p>
                        <strong>Method: </strong>
                        {order.paymentMethod}
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Order Items</h2>
                        {order.orderItems.length===0 ? <Message variant='info'>
                        Your order is empty
                        </Message> : (
                        <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                            {order.orderItems.map((item, index) => (
                            <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                                <Row>
                                <Col md={1}>
                                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded></Image>
                                </Col>

                                <Col>
                                    <Link to={'/product/'+item.product}>{item.name}</Link>
                                </Col>

                                <Col md={4}>
                                    {item.qty} X ${item.price} = ${(item.qty * item.price).toFixed(2)}
                                </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            ))}
                        </ListGroup>
                        )}
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    </ListGroup>

                    
                </Col>
                <Col md={4}>
                    <Card>
                    <ListGroup varaint='flush'>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <h2>Order Summary</h2>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                <Col>Item:</Col>
                                <Col>${order.itemsPrice}</Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                <Col>Shipping:</Col>
                                <Col>${order.shippingPrice}</Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                <Col>Tax:</Col>
                                <Col>${order.taxPrice}</Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                <Col>Total:</Col>
                                <Col>${order.totalPrice}</Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            {/* <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Button
                                type='button'
                                className='btn-block'
                                disabled={order.orderItems === 0}
                                onClick={placeOrder}
                                >
                                Place Order
                                </Button>
                            </ListGroup.Item> */}
                    </ListGroup>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
            )
}

export default OrderScreen
```

**orderActions.js:**

```
export const getOrderDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try{
        dispatch({
            type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
        })

        const {
            userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState()


        const config = {
            headers:{
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer '+userInfo.token,
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.get(
            '/api/orders/'+id,
            config
        )
        
        dispatch({
            type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })


    }catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type:ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
            payload:error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

In **App.js:** I have imported **OrderScreen** and inserted

```
<Route path='/order/:id' component={<OrderScreen/>} />
```

in **Routes** container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Matched leaf route at location "/order/34" does not have an element.
> This means it will render an with a null value by default resulting in
> an "empty" page.

The `react-router-dom@6` `Route` component doesn't have any `component` prop. The `Route` renders all content on a single `element` prop. The error is saying you have a `Route` with no element to render.

```
<Route path='/order/:id' element={<OrderScreen />} />
```

After this, the `OrderScreen` component will have an issue accessing the `id` route path param as there are now also not any route props. The above JSX should make it overtly clear that no props are passed to `OrderScreen`. Use the `useParams` hook to access the route path params

```
...
import { ... useParams, ... } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function OrderScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { id } = useParams();

  const { order, error, loading } = useSelector(state => state.orderDetails);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!order || String(order._id) !== id){
      dispatch(getOrderDetails(id))
      console.log("yes")
    }
  }, [dispatch, order, id]);

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>;
  }

  // Don't mutate state!! Compute derived total price when rendering.
  const orderItemsPrice = order.orderItems.reduce(
    (acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty,
    0
  ).toFixed(2);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}

export default OrderScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

exsample :

```
<Route path='userPage/:userId' element={ <UserPage /> } />
```

//    in other page that you want redirect to userPage :

```
<Link to={`userPage/${userId}`} > go to user page </Link>
```

//   in userPage component you can take UserId using useParams hook :

```
const {userId} = useparams( )
```